# Enable/Disable debug code dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, dynamic

I'm writing a decent sized JavaScript animation library, that I would like to include debugging code in. I could easily do a check :

```
if(myLib.debugger){
   console.warn('warning message');
}
```

However if this runs a couple thousand times a second, it would eventually cause performance issues. Add in a few more checks throughout the code and the effect will be even more noticeable.

What I'm wondering is if it would be possible to check onload if the debugger should be enabled, and if so... turn something like this:

```
//debugger if(!this.name) console.warn('No name provided');
```

into:

```
if(!this.name) console.warn('No name provided');
```

Leaving the code commented if its not enabled, and uncommenting it if it is, thus removing any possible performance issues. Could this be done somehow with a regular expression on the entire script if loaded in through ajax? I'm trying to avoid the need for 2 versions of the same code, lib.dbug.js and a lib.js.

Cross browser compatibility is not of great importance for this (I'm really only worried about new browsers), I see it as nice to have item. If its possible however, it would be a great thing to have.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a simple wrapper called debug() instead of console.warn(), and for production, set debug=Boolean;

Comment: It seems the best solution will be to manage this code with multiple files, I'll just need to write a good macro or something to strip out all the `console` calls in the deployable+readable version. It would have been really nice to have the minified version automatically strip all the comments, but oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to check if the debugger should be disabled and if so, replace it with a mock object that does nothing at the very start of your script:

```
if (!myLib.debugger) {
    window.console = (function () {
        var newConsole = {};
        var key;

        for (key in window.console) {
            if (typeof window.console[key] === 'function') {
                newConsole[key] = function () {};
            }
        }

        return newConsole;
    }());
}
```

The overhead of this approach should be negligible.

Comment: If I do that, I disable all warnings that the end user might want to display. I could very easily see someone wanting to disable my debug code but still display some themselves.

Comment: @ericjbasti If you are running your code in a closure (the `(function () { ... }())` idiom) then you can make a local `console` instead, which will be accessible only to your own code.  `var console; if (myLib.debugger) { console = window.console; } else { console = /* code in answer that builds a mock console */ }`

Comment: Interesting, that is not a path I even thought about. That just might be the ticket, I'll have to test that out.

Comment: On a pure "anti-code-kruft" mission I would still make sure that the production version of this library doesn't include dead code or extensive comments. Its fine for development but should be stripped out for production.

Comment: @scunliffe As an ideologue, I agree. As a pragmatist, remove the no-op debugging code only when it causes problems.

Comment: This method work for most situation. I think my goals are just unrealistic. One thing to note for anyone thinking of using this method... performance wise its actually faster to do an `if` statement than it is to run an empty function. You don't see it right away, but when you have 4000 objects calling these functions 30+ times a second... it adds up.

Comment: @ericjbasti That makes sense, since function calls have more overhead compared to inline code -- however, in the big scheme of things it might not be a problem.  It depends on the application.  As always, benchmark the entire application and optimize when necessary.

Comment: @ericjbasti See [this benchmark I made](http://jsperf.com/mock-function-vs-condition). On my system the mock approach is about 40% slower, but completed ~83 million calls per second (compared to ~140 million with the conditional).  Unless your log message frequency per second is in the millions, I stand by my statement that the overhead of a no-op function call is negligible.  :)

Comment: @cdhowie I completely agree about the trade offs of this method. I've even made the exact same jsperf in the past, and had similar results. The number of times I would make this type of call would really only be on initialization of objects, and certain interaction, so it shouldn't be an issue. My original hope was to find a method that would actually remove the debug code when minified... thus my //comment idea. I almost alway run into a struggle between optimizations, and usability. This is one of those cases.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a JavaScript library... then I'd expect as a 3rd party developer that I could download/use 2 versions. The production version (no debug, AND minimized). If I wanted to debug, I would point to the debug version of the library instead.

e.g.

```
<script src="foo-lib-min.js"></script>
<!-- swap to this for debugging <script src="foo-lib-full.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: I agree and that may be the path I have to follow... I guess I'm just trying to avoid having 2 copies to manage.